# Extending fiat transaction log to support cryptocurrency

Tags: sql-server, database-design, sql-server-2012

Let's assuming that I have an existing database that retaings fiat currency transaction as described below with `decimal (18, 4)`.

Now, I would like to record bitcoin, ethereum and erc20 token transactions.

```
Transaction
------------------
TransactionID
CurrencyID
UserID
DebitAmount  decimal(18, 4)
CreditAmount decimal(18, 4)
```

The decimal precision of cryptocurrency is suggested as follows:

```
 decimal (16, 8)  -- bitcoin
 decimal (30, 18) -- ethereum / erc20 token
```

**I am thinking of just:**

1. Treating bitcoin, ethereum, erc20 token as new currency in the `Currency` table.
2. Changing the `DebitAmount` and `CreditAmount` directly to `decimal(30, 18)`.
3. Applying `decimal(30, 18)` data type changes to all the tables that retain currency amount.

**My questions are:**

1. Any possible impact to original currency amount conversion that I need to look after for when I increase the precision (eg. currency rate change `DebitAmount * 1.023`)?
2. Am I doing this in the "correct" way?
3. Is there any other better approach/alternative to this?

Answer (score 3):

> Any possible impact to original currency amount conversion that i need to look after for when i increase the precision?

Yes.

Carefully review your calculations against the table here: [Precision, scale, and length](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), because you can have loss of precision when multiplying decimals:

> The result precision and scale have an absolute maximum of 38. When a
>   result precision is greater than 38, it's reduced to 38, and the
>   corresponding scale is reduced to try to prevent truncating the
>   integral part of a result.